# Print to JList Char by Char

Tags: java, swing, jlist, concatenation

I was wondering if there was a way to print a String to a JList char by char with a pause between each char.

If I were printing this to the console, I would iterate through str.toCharArray(), then print() each char (same line), then pause before going on to the next. It would look like someone was typing.

If I wanted to print "Testing," it would first print the "t", then the "e" a second later, then the "s", and so on.

Comment: Add each character to the list model...

Comment: Please explain a bit more. Is there a time delay involved? What would the user see/experience? Are you really asking about how to use a Swing Timer?

Comment: append the chars one below another? u can do the same and set the model of the jlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic process is the same as it would be for the console.

You need to break down the `String` into characters and then add each character to a `ListModel`...

```
DefaultListModel<Character> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
String value = "Testing";
for (char c : value.toCharArray()) {
    model.addElement(c);
}
```